# How to solve "Missing required account on accountable invoice line" in odoo7?

Tags: odoo-8

In odoo8, I got this warning "Missing required account on accountable invoice line" while posting my bill in subscription module. Please let me know how to resolve this!

Answer (score 1):

You need to install an accounting module based on your country
for India, you need to install an Indian accounting -> l10n_in

Comment: this solved it for me, thanks a lot! +1

Answer (score 0):

Well in odoo15 the solution was to goto company in developer mode..
Edit it
In form view add this field in the form view

Once you have selected and refreshed the screen you would notice the field is empty. simply edit and select the relevant receivable account and save. Now you would be able to close the session accordingly and at ease.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue, and it turns out I was missing the correct acounting module for my country as per Ritesh's comment.

I went to Settings > Invoicing and at the top there was a section for "Choose accounting module". I had to install the correct one (Hong Kong in my case) and then it automatically populated and I can now correctly create invoices.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, my client was using Odoo 16, I forgot to set up the defaults for some accounts in Invoicing Settings; like Suspense Account, Outstanding Receipts, and Outstanding Payments